# AR Aged Past Due Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

I am currently working on a generic inquiry that pulls the AR aging past due in Acumatica; however, when I try to match the numbers with the AR Aging Past Due report in Acumatica the numbers do not match. I thought it may be a conditions issue in the GI, but I can not quite understand how it is getting the wrong numbers or how to fix it. I need to get the current balance for each customer. Some of the customers are right and the others are wrong. I know that the data I need comes from a temporary DAC in Acumatica, but I didn't know if there was another way besides using the prebuilt inquiry in the Acunaitca Demo company.
I need it to take the =credit limit - (unreleased + remaining credit limit)-open orders balance, but I can not find any way to do that.

Any Idea?

We are trying to use the inquiry for AR Past Due dashboard within our Acumatica instance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with a simple GI that will group by customer and sum by current balance which is:
ARREGISTER.DOCBAL and or ARREGISTER.CURYDOCBAL (currency related).
Audit those values first and then you can continue to build upon the formula to account for credit limit etc.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must add the customer ID as a field in the result grid but uncheck the visible field.